# How can you manage Ads API Account list linked with an app via API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-marketing-api

You can manage that list manually via this URL: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APP_ID>/marketing-api/settings/

You can add up to 5/25/unlimited number of accounts based on your access level. My question is - can you add/remove accounts **to this list** with some sort of API request? I can't find anything related in the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Ad Accounts are not linked to an app, they are linked to a Business Manager or a user account. Apps are the connection between Business Manager or users and Ad Accounts, so they can make API calls through an app to manage their ad accounts.

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/193B8.png)

This being said, you cannot delete an Ad Account, you can only disable it.

If your Business Manager has an App with Standard Access, you can create new ad accounts or view the ones owned or accessed by your Business Manager:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/assets/v2.8

Python example:

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
business = Business(fbid=business_id)
params = {
    'currency': 'EUR',
    'end_advertiser': 'NONE',
    'funding_id': '123123123',
    'media_agency': 'NONE',
    'name': 'New Ad Account',
    'partner': 'NONE',
    'timezone_id': 1
}
adaccount= business.create_ad_account(params=params)
allAdAccounts = business.get_owned_ad_accounts({AdAccount.Field.name})
```

Comment: The thread is not about creating/deleting real Ad Accounts, it is about managing the list of accounts application has access to. I've edited the text a bit, to make it more clear.